# Excel - Get same word in a column

Tags: excel

How do i get same word in excel for a single column??

For e.g "hair, skin, lifestyle, makeup, skin, makeup"

i want it to replace this with

"hair, skin, lifestyle, makeup"

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Remove Duplicates` feature.

Image below contains instructions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply, but what i meant was single cell. sorry my mistake.
So i have "hair, skin, lifestyle, makeup, skin, makeup" and i want to remove the duplicates words.
[image: Image below contains instructions.]